# How to send (,) comma separated values as STRING to query in sphinx?

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I want to pass values (,) comma separated STRING to sphinx query. How can I do that?

**data** is a coulmn in **table** having (,) comma separated values.

e.g. data = abcd, pqr, xyz which should treat as 'abcd', 'pqr, 'xyz' while passing to `IN` clause

```
sql_query = select UUID_SHORT() AS id, t.name from table t where key IN(t.data);
```

When I call this then it should treat data as (,) comma separated STRING values & not non-string.

Comment: I don't quite get the question. Do you want to 1) find a document with 'abcd, pqr, xyz' by querying just 'pqr' or 'xyz' or 2) you want to index only those documents where `key` is one of 'abcd' or 'pqr' or 'xyz'. In the 1st case you should jsut index the whole t.data as a field in Sphinx and then the sphinxql query will be smth like "select * from index where match('xyz')".

Comment: Or you can use MVA attributes, but then you need to convert the values into numbers (using e.g. mysql function crc32() ). In the 2nd case smth like "where d.data like '%key%'" should work or if you want it to be stricter then maybe smth like where concat(',', d.data, ',') like '%,key,%'".

Comment: Yes. I anti make it in OR or like abcd, xyz... in IN clause